# Remove staples from a hard board

Tags: office-supplies

I prepare some religious decorations using hardboard in each may of the year. When the festivals are over, I dissemble the decorations and reassemble on next year. I use staples to assemble it. Is there an easy way to remove staples from hardboard?

What I have tried so far?

I have tried a staple remover like [this one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001E641P4).  But it was not 100% successful. When I try that machine to straight out the two folded ends, It does not straight both the ends. Sometimes it straight a the left side or the right side. Then it will be hard to pull the staple pin from the other side. It is annoying. Since I have to deal with lots of decorations in festival times I have to remove about 1000 staples when dissembling. So, if there a efficient way to do this, it will be great.

Comment: A remover like the one you linked to, and a needlenose pliers, are what I usually use.

Answer (score 2):

***You could try:***

- Using pliers(or a similar device) and a pair of wire cutters. By cutting the staple in half, you can pull up either side easily.
- You can use the pliers to just pull the staples up. This is easier on staples that are not close to the board. Pulling directly upwards is key.

  ---

Using a screwdriver to loosen the staples helps in either method. You can simply take a flat head screwdriver and put it under the staple and then using it like a lever pull upwards. Once the staple is a little bit up, you can do either method that is named above.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the type of stapler you have, it might have a staple remover 'wedge' at the back of it which I have found to be very useful in removing staples from almost anything.  [image]

This image shows sort of what I am talking about (not the best image but the best I could find at short notice) you just slide the little piece of metal underneath the staple (might require some jimmying) and then use the stapler as a sort of lever and lift the staple out from the board.
I have also used a few different things in place of this when it hasn't been available:

- Scissors
- A pen (not a crappy Biro that will just snap but a decent strength one)
- A knife / fork / spoon
- Screw driver (flat head works best)
- Basically anything strong and flat that would fit underneath the staple and you would be able to use as a lever to remove the staple

You can buy special tools similar yet separate to the one shown above:
[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: I would go for the end of an old table knife, old because it may get scratches. Table knives have round ends, which will not damage your board and are sturdy enough to take the forces needed. And I would start the process at the side where the two ends are rather than with the one bar in the middle.